# Big-endian arithmetic in C

Tags: c, endianness

Is there a convenient way of doing arithmetic with big-endian data? Here's what I've been doing (in pseudocode):

```
main:
    unsigned int big_endian_number = 0x12345678;
    int multiplier = 7;

    unsigned int little_endian_number = reverse_the_bytes(big_endian_number);
    little_endian_number = little_endian_number * multiplier;

    big_endian_number = reverse_the_bytes(little_endian_number);
```

This seems direct, but verbose and error-prone. There has to be a better way.

Comment: You could always do your arithmetic on a big-endian platform; you should be able to find a PPC mac pretty cheap these days. =)

Comment: Network byte order is big endian, use ntohl (network to host) that will convert to your local endian, then htonl to convert back.

Comment: Convert the number to the format of your current platform, perform arithmetic, convert back.

Comment: @StephenCanon ops wrong language!

Comment: @Ironside: make that an answer.

Comment: Whatever the endianness of the machine, 0x3 * 0x3 == 0x9.  Sometimes the 0x9 is stored with null bytes after it, sometimes before, but you don't care if you just want to use arithmetic operators.

Comment: @WilliamPursell and what in case of a carry to the next byte? Of course byte order matters!

Comment: @Junix.  No, it doesn't.  0x8 * 0x8 == 0x40, no matter the endianness, because the compiler converts 0x8 and 0x40 into the appropriate order.

Comment: @WilliamPursell See my comment to your answer. I think you missed the point.

Comment: @user1505713: What would be the exact thing you want? For the multiplication?

Comment: It depends on your target processor.  If it's x86 or x86-64, use the network method as others have suggested.  Some processors support switching endianness.

Comment: @user1505713 In order to clearify your question, could you please add the information if your question arose from the need to deal with "external" big endian data or from the fact that you are working with a big endian machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network byte order is big endian, use ntohl (network to host) that will convert to your local endian, then htonl to convert back.

I can post a code example if necessary but I think that's fairly straight forward.

Comment: I'd like to add that a strategy dealing with "network" data should be applied for the whole application. My recommondation is converting all the "network data" consequently into host format on receptionn and redering it to network format on transmission. This would prevent nasty "i forgot the conversion" bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would define some functions in a header to do the arithmetic ops you need:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

static inline uint32_t BEAdd_u32(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    return htonl(ntohl(x) + ntohl(y));
}
```

and use those instead of littering your code with conversions.

Comment: It would be better to consequently convert the incoming data to host format, do whatever you like and render the data to network format instad of implementing every operation you want to execute for the data.

Comment: @junix: oh, I absolutely agree; questioner doesn't seem to want to do that for some reason (that or he just wants to perform one or two operations on the data, in which case it's basically a moot point).

Comment: I agree too, but I can't hold back this "good advice" as I have seen too many bugs deriving from such "shortcuts" because one thought in the beginning "it's only for one or two". These are the exact assumptions that are lost over time and the time will come when someone patches a bug in the code. Hence do it right from the beginning and avoid this possibility :-)

Comment: Totally agreed, one should convert to local endianness, then perform all the computing it needs and convert back to big endian when feeding back the network (or anything else that needs big endian data). This way, data is only converted one time when needed. I think it's a reason why you insist on that point @junix don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

This question makes no sense.  If you write `x = 0x12345678; x *= 2`, then x will have have the value `0x2468acf0`.  Whether that is stored in memory with the `f0` in the first byte or the `24` in the first byte is totally irrelevant.  The whole point of using a high level language is that it works and you don't care how `0x12345678` is stored.  (That is, the compiler converts the literal `0x2468acf0` into the appropriate representation on the box, and you don't have to worry about it.)

Comment: You are missing the point. If you have values only inside your program you are right. As soon as you leave the context of your program (e.g. communicating over Network, or storing data in binary form) endianness ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness ) matters. No compiler can help you there. The only way to ship around this problem is to abstract "foreign" data properly on entering and leaving your program. Hence -1 for your answer.

Comment: The sample code is not communicating outside the process.  It uses string literals like `0x12345678` which are automatically converted by the compiler.  If the questioner is trying to convert a char array, then `htonl` and `ntohl` are relevant.  As asked, the question is totally meaningless.

Comment: I think we both are just guessing about the intention of the OP. Personally I thought he has to deal with foreign data which comes in big endian because I think your statement is clear to everyone dealing with endianness. Also I think your answer is dangerous as it's only onesided. I would have preferred to see you asking if your asumption is correct in the comments before posting this answer.